# Checkbox CSS Not Working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a checkbox look like the rest of the buttons on my site: [pencilfactorygames.com/createaccount.html](http://pencilfactorygames.com/createaccount.html)
Here's my css:

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
    display:none;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222 50%, #111 50%);
    border-radius: 5px;
    color:#FFF;
    display:inline-block;
    width:19px;
    height:19px;
    margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0F0 50%, #F00 50%);
}
```

and here's my html: `<input type="checkbox" name="ToS">`
When I test it, it just looks like the plain default checkbox.
Edit: Fixed, Forgot tomake checkbox invisible

Comment: Read up on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css, and this: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Comment: Looks like you forgot to include checkbox styles in your main.css

Answer (score 1):

You can style a checkbox by hiding the real checkbox input and substituting it with a graphical representation of it that gets checked/unchecked with javascript `onclick();` method and sets the checked status to the proper checkbox input.

Answer (score 0):

On the CSS file that is being loaded, there is actually no CSS regarding the input type = "checkbox", so no style is being applied to the checkbox, only the other input areas.

Comment: so how should I make it work

Comment: You can load the CSS that you have on this page into main.css that is loading onto your page. The above poster that mentioned the JS method onclick(); is also right, and can be another solution.

Comment: Also Eugene said the same as I did in his comment on your original problem. Just include the CSS on this page to your main.css that gets loaded on your site.

Answer (score 0):

Styling checkboxes can be a pain with pure CSS. For a jQuery solution try Prettycheckable (http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/)